# gedit - files in File Browser I never opened

Tags: gedit, tmp

Typically, gedit has the file or folders I've been recently working on in the File Browser on the left side of the window. Today, I opened gedit and found that it was listing things like "Pulse-(trash characters)", "ssh-(similar trash characters)", and the /tmp folder. I've not seen this behaviour before -- I certainly didn't open these files, and I'm the only one who uses this computer. Why would the File Browser list these files?

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file through gedit Linux implicitly create a temp file in the /tmp directory with **~** sign which indicate this is a temporary file actually whatever you make change in that file that dose not effect the physical file directly rather it effect the tmp file when you save the file then actually the tmp file replace the physical file. some times what happens due to some inconsistent state of your system environment tmp file with **~** sign remains there. I think this happens in your case.

Comment: I've seen the files with a ~ before, they typically reflect the filename they came from. This is different; files and folders which I've never touched were displaying in the File Browser.